# Resizing font to fit the current screen size on a website

Tags: html, css

If I have a font set to a particular size for a desktop screen, can I reduce it using CSS3 @media Rule to also fit well in Mobile devices?

I have this line of code below:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 150px) {
.log {font-size: 10px}
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="log" style="font-size: 35px;">
HEADER TEXT<br />
</div>
</body>
```

But it is not responsive when I open the site on my mobile device!!! What am I doing wrong???

Comment: 150px seems quite small. Also, the `style` attribute overrides the CSS in the `<style>` tag. Don’t use the attribute.

Comment: you set `min` at the mediaqueries. which means all devices that have minimum screen width of 150px. I guess what you are looking for is `max` . and 150px...that's too small..there are no devices that i know of that have under 320px and access to internet :)

Comment: In case you don't know it: There is http://fittextjs.com/ , which does what you want (but is a javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the media query wrong. It specifies font-size to devices with width higher than 150px. You should use `max-width` in your media query. What that does is applies the desired css to device up to that width.
For example :

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 920px) {
.log {font-size: 10px}
}
```

This will apply `font-size: 10px` to devices with width below 920px.
And using inline styles will override css from your css file or `style` tag. So, avoid doing that and write all your css in css file or style tag.
I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The inline styling of the element is overriding the media query. Try this instead:

```css
.log {
font-size: 35px;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 150px) {
.log {font-size: 10px}
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="log">
HEADER TEXT<br />
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS instead of `px` you can use `vw` (viewport width) or `vh` (viewport height) for font size

Open the code snippet in **full page** mode, and resize your browser, you will see that text size is the same according to screen size

- First text will never fall in two lines, it will be smaller on smaller screen sizes
- Second text will change font size when you change your browser height

Usually, the `vw` will do all you need

```html
<style>
.view-width {
 font-size: 5vw
}
.view-height {
 font-size: 10vh
}
</style>

<div class="view-width">Some text according to screen Width</div>
<div class="view-height">Some text according to screen Height</div>
```